# Could information in a boundary be modified once encoded in holographic principle?

Tags: cosmology, quantum-information, holographic-principle, multiverse

There are models of universes where holographic principle has a different correspondence (there is absolutely no reason to assume that this would hold true for all possible universes. You could have a universe there the amount of information in a volume is proportional to the the square of the surface area, or perhaps there is not general correlation at all)

For those models of universes where holographic principle does not even exist (there is not general correlation at all), could we modify that model and make them have a holographic correspondence but keeping all of its original properties?

Also, could the encoded information be modified in the boundary so even if the bulk was a universe that would fit in holography the boundary would be a universe that would be not compatible with holography?

Comment: "There are models of universes where holographic principle has a different correspondence" What models are you talking about? What even motivates these strange, vague, and barely comprehensible questions? It's like asking if you can change the number of sides in a triangle. Maybe yes, maybe no, but it's not really a triangle any more if you do that.

Comment: @Sue K Dccia What do you mean by 'holography principle does not exist'? For me such kind of duality is a general rule, the only problem is that maybe the correspondence is not always something like a holography(low dim boundary encodes the high dim bulk) for different systems. Maybe we should just call it a duality instead of holography.

Comment: @MitchellPorter For example: Consider that string theory is true. Consider that holographic principle applies in our universe. The universe in the boundary would be a copy of our universe. Could there be any theoretical way of changing that information already encoded in the boundary, so the universe there would stop being a copy of our universe and could be transformed into a universe where, for example, string theory wouldn't be right?

Comment: @MitchellPorter and what do you want to say with the example of the triangle? Couldn't information in the boundary be changed but keeping holographic principle basis? And when you say "maybe no" is it becaise there could be some cases where information encoded in the boundary could not be modified? If yes, in what cases information could not be modified?

Comment: If you change the number of sides in a triangle, it's not a triangle any more. Similarly, if you change just one member of a holographic dual pair, you don't have a holographic duality any more. The elements of a holographic duality are two dual *descriptions* of the *same* thing. There isn't a "copy of our universe" "in the boundary". The boundary *description* is of the same universe, but with fewer dimensions explicit, compared to the bulk description...

Comment: I'm sure you could have a holographic pseudo-duality (to give it a name), in which you have a boundary description with a true holographic dual, and then some other bulk universe which only *resembles* the true dual. But in itself, that is no more meaningful than saying 1+2 exactly equals 3, which is close to 3.1.

Comment: @MitchellPorter and could one of the descriptions change and be radically different from the other description? I mean,could there be a model that would start with a holographic duality or a "pseudo" holographic duality that would somehow change one of the "sides" (for example the boundary) so the boundary would have a totally different description from the bulk? I mean,could the boundary change and be radically different from the bulk? And vice versa?

Comment: @MitchellPorter maybe this is a poor analogy but consider this: the boundary encodes information from the bulk. It wpuld be sort of encoding information about a room in a paper (drawing the room in the paper). Imagine we could move the ink in the paper. We could change the drawing into something else. Would something somewhat similar happen somehow with holographic cosmology?

Comment: I'm tired of this topic, I won't be answering any more.

Comment: Answering your questions is tedious because the real point of the questions has nothing to do with the actual details of holographic duality or 5d black holes or whatever, it always comes back to topics like: "can we make impossible things happen", "could we think of impossible things if we changed the laws that our brains use", and so on...

Comment: The relations between logic, possibility, conceivability, physics of the brain, and so on are interesting in their own way. Nonetheless, it is a lot of work to answer technical questions about physics, and it's just not interesting to make that effort, when the real issues seem to have nothing to do with all that physical detail...

Comment: Are you capable of explaining the *motivation* for your original question? *Why* do you want to know if information in a holographic boundary can be modified in a way that disconnects it from its dual partner?